# convexHull - "Invalid arguments" - OpenCV 2.4.9

Tags: android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface, convex-hull

I have this C ++ OpenCV code ...

```
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
findContours(bin.clone(), contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

// Find the convex hull object of the external contour
vector<vector<Point> >hull( contours.size() );
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
Error here -->   convexHull(Mat(contours[i]), hull[i], false);
}
```

... and am using the jni to use it on an Android project, but is having a conflict in function arguments "convexHull":

"Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
void convexHull(const cv::_InputArray &, const cv::_OutputArray &, bool, bool)
'"
I wonder how to get around this error ... I am using OpenCV version 2.4.9

Thanks!

Comment: This works for me. But try with `convexHull(contours[i], hull[i], false, true);`

Comment: Thanks for listening, but still displays the same error. The error disappears when step  `convexHull(Mat(contours[i]),Mat( hull[i]), false, true);`
but will give an error at runtime. What I do not understand is that if I close the project and open it again, the error only appears when I open the .cpp file that contains the call. But if you do not open it, I can build the application and generate the .apk and yet still performs the convexHull normally.

Comment: really, because so does some calls as:
`to_string (number)`
`circle (...);`
`putText (...);`                                                                                                I am looking for some solution to this problem. Thank you!